# Calling Java Script with no function name in WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control

Im using Winforms and I'm not familiar with web languages.
Im navigating a webpage which loading different pages under the same url with webbrowser.
In order to reach my aimed page, I have to go through many pages and clicks via code.
I thought of js as shortcut. This is the onyl piece of code that refers to the page in the website source

```
<script src="https://string/assets/js/pages/accountsproducts/myaccounts/myaccounts.js?__ctst__=1502859802194" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can I call it via code ?
Thanks

Comment: Psst. Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was a good idea to ask it here. I know nearly nothing about web topic. Is it possible somehow ?

Comment: I don't know the page you're looking at. And by this explanation I have barely any idea of what you're talking about. Could you please explain what exactly you're dealing with, what behaviour you want (in contrary to the current one), what you have tried and how this did not succeed/what the problem was.

Comment: It'd also be good to see which bit of the "linked" code you'd like to use.

Comment: You are right. Hence I dont know how it works, Im not able to ask the right question in the right form. Basicly, there are different pages, and they are triggered by clicks which on located on the previous pages. I want to skip some steps ( all pages run different queries and causes time) and load that page from the main page via code. I know, you still don't know the page. I think, It's more complicated than I thought when I was posting the question.